# why google chart didn't display the data in the chart

Tags: javascript, php

I don't understand why my google chart didn't display the data?
the code didn't show the wrong, but it is not have data in the chart. Please let me know why this happen.Thank you.
this is my php code.

```
<?php
$query="SELECT Time, Temperature FROM (SELECT Time, Temperature FROM fish_tank_parameter order by Time desc limit 10)as a order by Time";
$result=db_connection($query);
function db_connection($query){
    $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hfjq_race_info");
    return mysqli_query($link,$query);
}

$rows = array();
$table = array();

$table['cols'] = array(
    array(
        'label' => 'Time',
        'type' => 'number'
    ),
    array(
        'label' => 'Temperature',
        'type' => 'number'
    )
);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $sub_array = array();
    $datetime = explode("." , $row["Time"]);
    $sub_array[] = array(
        "v" => 'Date('. $datetime[0] .'000)'
    );
    $sub_array[] = array(
        "v" => $row["Temperature"]
    );
    $rows[] = array(
        "c" => $sub_array
    );
}
$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
?>
```

this is my javascript code.

```
        google.charts.load('current',{'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/test/get_temp.php",
                dataType: "json",
                    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
                    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('tempflot'));
                    chart.draw(data,{width: 800, height: 400});
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Show us the source code (only the js) that your code produces. (Add this information to your question as an edit.)  Are you printing the json to screen?

Comment: Did you check your browser's js console for errors?

Comment: Please refrain from upvoting incomplete questions.

Comment: @Elvis if you don't provide the necessary details, your question will be closed as Off-topic: Why isn't my code working.

Comment: Please improve your post in order to get votes and a proper response. You should:
- Fix your grammar and vocabulary (use caps as needed not everything in lowercase, better puntuation,...)
- Provide the console output. Open your browser inspector with F12 and provide the error or the output in the console tab.

Anyway, try debugging your code or adding traces with console.log in JS and with var_dump in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your json data is correctly generated, you will need to echo your json data in your php file and adjust the drawChart function in your javascript.

PHP:

```
echo $jsonTable;  // just before closing php tag
```

JS:

```
function drawChart() {
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/test/get_temp.php",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('tempflot'));
    chart.draw(data,{width: 800, height: 400});
}
```

This is laid out in the Google Chart Documentation : https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example

Comment: @Elvis If my answer corrects the issues, please award the green tick to my answer.  If there is still something not quite right, please explain to me by leaving me a comment.  All questions on StackOverflow deserve resolution.